# Using an index in the name attribute and have a custom error message using vee validate?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have a list of user cards on one page. 
I need to use an index to differentiate the field names on each of these cards.
ex. `userDob${i}`

I also have to create a custom message for these user inputs.
Normally for custom messages, I can simply write

```
custom: {
  userDob: {
    required: 'User dob is required',
    date_format: 'Please enter a dob in the correct format (yyyy-mm-dd)'
  },
}
```

In this case, I will need to have a more dynamic approach, by somehow ignoring the index, or be able to assign an alias to use in my custom messaging instead of the name attribute being the property name. 
I could have sworn vee validate had a way of using an alias, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Vee Validate allows you to set an alternative value for name by using "data-vv-name" and "data-vv-as" for displaying the message to the user.

I don't have your input field code, but you should be able to add something like this:

```
:data-vv-name="`${value.field_name}`"  //e.g user_name
:data-vv-as="key"   // Name
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen this as well and thought it may help with my solution. Unfortunately, I'm not looking to change the name of the input in the default message, I'm trying to create an entire custom message, but would like to match it to a different property that does not require an index. This solution will still need to have an index provided for the data-vv-name attribute, as it will act the exact same way as the default name attribute I believe.

Comment: In that case, can't you just use the default custom rule example from the docs? https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#using-the-custom-rule